# Update keystore/truststore while Jetty is running

Tags: java, security, jetty

I'm running an embedded jetty server with SSL.
I would like to update the contents of the keystore/truststore while jetty is running, and have jetty pick up on these changes.

The keystore objects that i give jetty's secured connector will always give the most updated values. The problem is that the SSLContext caches whatever the keystores had when it was started and the only way i can think of to update it, would be just to reload the SSLContext.

The only solution to this i can think of would be to extend SSLContextSpi, and make sure it would have the latest information from the keystore/truststore. But i would really like to avoid that.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The amount of caching that the JVM does internally for SSLContext means you'll have your work cut out for you.  Good luck, and be careful of memory leaks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we came up with eventually was to close all existing connectors and openning new ones, that would basically reload the content of the keystore/truststore without having to restart jetty completely.